# Accessing an array of enums inside of an enum

Tags: java, arrays, enums, nullpointerexception

Not sure if my title sets up for my question. Basically I have an enum that contains various values for some blocks I am creating (yes this is for a minecraft mod). My goal is make a "spec sheet" that has all of the values contained and then I feed them into my BlockMaker class which actually does the heavy lifting.

I have my base blocks defined as an enum with values and a constructor. One of the values (or set of values) defines if the blocks should have alternate blocks such as stairs. My original idea was use a series of booleans that pertained to each alternate block. Then I had the idea to create another enum which simply contained all of the names of the alternate blocks. Instead of booleans I just added an array of the enums as a value of the block enums. The blockMaker class would check which enums exist in the array and create the blocks accordingly. But the issue now is I cannot figure out how to get access to them, I keep getting `nullPointerException` when I run the game.

With the said I am also not even sure an array of enums is even the best way to store the data. If anyone has a better idea I would like to know.

Here is the code I am working with;

"Main" enum with block values;

```
public enum UBCBlockConstants {

TEST_ROCK("testRock", IGNEOUS, 1.0F, 1.0F, new ConstructTypes[]{STONE, COBBLESTONE, BRICKS, SLAB, STAIRS, WALL}),

String unlocalizedName = "";
UBCRockTypes rockType;
Float hardness = 0.0F;
Float resistance = 0.0F;
ConstructTypes[] constructTypes;

UBCBlockConstants(String unlocalizedName, UBCRockTypes rockType, Float hardness, Float resistance, ConstructTypes[] constructTypes) {

    this.unlocalizedName = unlocalizedName;
    this.rockType = rockType;
    this.hardness = hardness;
    this.resistance = resistance;
    this.constructTypes = constructTypes;

}

public UBCRockTypes getBlockType() { return rockType; }

public String getUnlocalizedName() { return unlocalizedName; }

public Float getHardness() {
    return hardness;
}

public Float getResistance(){
    return resistance;
}

public ConstructTypes[] getConstructTypes() { return constructTypes; }

}
```

ConstructType enum;

```
public enum ConstructTypes {

STONE,
COBBLESTONE,
BRICKS,
SLAB,
STAIRS,
WALL;

}
```

As I was asking above, is an array of enums nested inside an enum really the best way to do this? Would it better to use another storage method?

Comment: You should provide the code that throw the `NullPointerException` and the `BlockMaker.class` you mentioned. Although those error are usually not that hard to solve with a simple debugger,

Comment: You should consider using an `EnumSet<ConstructTypes>` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html